# How do I get a WPF element to respond to changes in a VB Module?

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, properties

Objects whose Properties are observed for changes must implement the System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged event to alert their WPF-element observers that a change has occurred.

If I have a Visual Basic Module whose Properties I wish to have observed by a WPF element, how should I go about routing the Properties of that Module through to the WPF, considering that Modules cannot, themselves, implement Interfaces?

EDIT: Modules are Static classes, for you C# readers, IIRC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define an event called [Property]Changed in your module, where [Property] is the name of the property that is changing. WPF will respond to these, as well as to the PropertyChanged events raised by INotifyPropertyChanged objects.

Comment: I can't get this to work, but I'm going to blame the project and mark this as the answer, which is looking more and more desperately cobbled-together and ghastly the longer I look at it (I didn't write it, so I don't have to take the blame :P ). I ended up making the Module into a Class, making all of my methods and attributes Shared and making all instances of the class into dumb reporter objects. But your answer sounds way cooler than doing it that way.